# Does separation of variables find all solutions to the 3-dimensional spherical time independent Schrödinger equation for a hydrogen atom?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, schroedinger-equation, hydrogen

I understand why it's OK to separate $\mathbf x$ and $t$ in the *time-dependent* equation. What's *not* clear to me is why, in the case of the 3-dimensional hydrogen atom, it's sufficient to find stationary states of the form $\psi(r, \theta, \varphi) = R(r)\Theta(\theta)\Phi(\varphi)$. Is every stationary state in this form? If not, do these states form a basis for the rest of the stationary states? If not, does that mean that there are other stationary states that this method does not account for, and which basic treatments simply ignore?

I am not very well versed in PDEs, so if the answer has to do with the nature of the spherical form of the hydrogen atom Hamiltonian, that's probably the source of my confusion.

Comment: [This answer on Math.SE](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1716871) seems to *mostly* answer my question—spherical polars *kind* of correspond $R^3$ with $[0, \infty) \times [0, \pi) \times S^1$, and the state space *kind* of corresponds to (some subset of) $\mathbb{C}^{R^3}$ and hence $\mathbb{C}^{[0, \infty) \times [0, \pi) \times S^1}$. Then, that answer indicates that we have an isomorphism with (some subset of) $\mathbb{C}^{[0, \infty)} \otimes \mathbb{C}^{[0, \pi)} \otimes \mathbb{C}^{S^1}$ which precisely corresponds the simple tensors—which form a basis—with the separable solutions.

Comment: But I'm not going to post my own answer on this question, because there's way too much dubious handwaving going on in the above logic, and I don't know enough to work it out properly.